# Date Conversion Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime

When I am using new Date(2012,12,28,10, 57, 00) its giving the result as **Sat Jan 28 2012 10:57:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)**. Why the month is jan instead of december. please help me to get the date in correct way.

Comment: There is no the `12th` month... it starts from `0` to `11`.

Answer (score 0):

Integer value representing the month, beginning with `0` for `January` to `11` for `December`.

Again `12` for `Jan` and it goes on...

### Updates:

Based on your [**comment**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992048/date-conversion-issues#comment31543924_20992171),

```
var date = new Date(2012, 12, 28, 10, 57, 00)
//retruns Mon Jan 28 2013 10:57:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Here both `month` and `year` get *incremented*

So I have added this condition

```
if (date.getMonth() === 0) {
    //I'm setting date to Dec and decrease year by 1
    date.setMonth(11);
    date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() - 1)
} else {
    //for other decrease month by 1
    date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 1);
}
```

Incase if you're go do formatting as `MM/dd/yyy HH:mm:ss` I have used like

```
var MM = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
var dd = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
var yyy = date.getFullYear();
var HH = ("0" + date.getHours()).slice(-2);
var mm = ("0" + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
var ss = ("0" + date.getSeconds()).slice(-2);
var final = MM + "/" + dd + "/" + yyy + " " + HH + ":" + mm + ":" + ss;
```

Finally, see it in

### [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehACr/4/)

Answer (score 0):

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date.

The month parameter in the constructor `new Date()` is '0' indexed. So 12 will be december (index is 11) + 1 month = january of the next year.